# unsupported media error 415 while trying to post

Tags: angular

Im trying to post my credntial for authenication but i get the unsupported media error:

```
 login(credentials) { 
console.log(credentials);
return this.http.post('http://localhost:59628/api/auth/login',
 JSON.stringify(credentials)).pipe(
map(response=>{

  console.log(response);
}))
 };
```

}

i also tried to add the header :

```
const httpOptions = {
 headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
}
```

but that does not work with pipe thought,any idea?

Comment: Why are you stringifying these credentials before passing to post method? I think this is why error appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 415 (Unsupported Media Type) status code indicates that the origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload is in a format not supported by this method on the target resource. The format problem might be due to the request's indicated Content-Type or Content-Encoding.

It could also be due to your stringified data you are sending.